# Transformation of normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, transformation

Suppose $X$~$N(0,1)$ and we know $\Bbb E[X^{2n}]$. Now let $Y$~$N(0,\sigma^2)$.

I have received knowledge from someone that, given this information, we know that $$\Bbb E[Y^{2n}]=\sigma^2\Bbb E[X^{2n}]$$
Is this accurate? If so, how do we know this?

Comment: why did you tag uniform distribution? did you mean to say that X ~ U(0,1)?

Comment: no sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition:

$$\mathbb{E}[Y^{2n}] = \int x^{2n}\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} dx $$ Let $t = x/\sigma$, so we can rewrite above as:
$$\sigma^{2n} \int t^{2n} \frac{e^{-t^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\sigma dt = \sigma^{2n} \int t^{2n}\frac{e^{-t^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} = \sigma^{2n} \mathbb{E}[X^{2n}]$$